# How to join neighbor cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some data which I recorded in a bad way, see the picture :

[image]

How can I format this into something like this:

```
Error 1               Error 2
(3.2 ± 1.97) E-04     (3.7 ± 1.3) E-03
(2.2 ± 0.72) E-04     etc
```

How can I do such a formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm writing now should actually be a comment and not an answer. Nonetheless, i have an answer to your problem. (i do not have have enough credit to comment :-P)
Step-1 First split your "Average error" into mantissa and exponent parts using the formula
(assuming the "Average error" is in A2) type the following formula in A4 `=INT(LOG(A2))`
This will take the exponent part in A4.
Step-2 Next for the mantissa part type the following formula in A5 `=A2/10^A4`
This will give the mantissa part in A5.
Repeat this for "Std.Dev.Error" as well. 
Now, take the +/- symbol from "Insert->Symbol" and put in a cell.
Now you can concatenate the numbers with "(" in the first part followed by numbers and ")E" in the last part. Look at the image for easy reference.
I hope this is what u want...
[image]

Comment: In some cases, the SD is going to be 1 or 2 magnitudes different than the average (Mean = 1.248e-4, SD = 4.82e-5).

Comment: Hi would it be possible to bring all the data to a common exponent value? then we could possibly use the same solution for the case you have commented. I'm working on it anyway....

Comment: Yes, instead use `=B2/(10^A4)` in B5 (you don't need B4).

Comment: Thanks @Prasanna, this seems really helpful. I will try it and select if works. also LDC3's question really applies for me.

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw How much data do you have to work on? Why I'm asking this to you, is because to address the comment raised by LDC3 - i'm working out a way to make all the exponent values same in the table. Only if there is considerable amount of data, it is worth all the effort. Please confirm the quantity of data you have....

Comment: @Prasanna hi, sorry for the late answer. The table can get a size like  10 x 100 (rows x columns)

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw, Request you to approve the answer to close the question or provide further requirement to take this further....

Comment: I really can't. Well, since yours is the most helpful answer anyway, I will just select it. I'm sure it will help me at some point :) Thanks !